# In Django, is there a way you can limit a user to registering for an event only once?

Tags: django, templates, view

I'm a newbie to Django, trying to build site to allow people to register for football matches.

At the moment, a user can register multiple times for the *same* match, which is obviously not ideal! Is there a way that I can identify if the currently logged in user has already registered, and then replace the register button with a message telling them that they have already registered? I guess I need some kind of Boolean value in my EventDetail view, and then I can make a conditional statement in the template, but I'm unsure as to how to implement this. I hope this question is clear, it's my very first post!

**views.py:**

```
class EventDetail(View):
    def get(self, request, id, *args, **kwargs):
        event = get_object_or_404(Event, pk=id)
        registrations = Registration.objects.filter(event=event)
        total_participants = 0
        for person in registrations:
            total_participants += 1
            if person.guest:
                total_participants += 1
        remaining_spaces = event.max_participants - total_participants
        template = "event_detail.html"
        context = {
            "event": event,
            "total_participants": total_participants,
            "registrations": registrations,
            "remaining_spaces": remaining_spaces,
        }
        return render(request, template, context)
```

**template**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

<p>{{ event.title }}</p>
<p>{{ total_participants }} / {{ event.max_participants }} ({{ remaining_spaces }} spot{{ remaining_spaces|pluralize }}
    remaining!)</p>
{% if total_participants < event.max_participants %}
<a href="{% url 'event_registration' event.id %}" class="btn">Register</a>

{% else %}
<p>This event has filled up.</p>
{% endif %}

<h2>Current Participants</h2>
<ul>
    {% for person in registrations %}
    <li>
        {{ person.name }}
        {% if person.guest %}
        +1
        {% endif %}
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>

{% endblock %}
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Event(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="event_posts")
    event_date_and_time = models.DateTimeField()
    venue = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    max_participants = models.IntegerField()
    extra_info = models.TextField(blank=True)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['event_date_and_time']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
    

class Registration(models.Model):

    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="event_registration")
    name = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ball = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    bibs = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    guest = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)
```

Comment: You can add a [unique constraint](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/constraints/#django.db.models.UniqueConstraint) on your Registration model to make the event and the user unique together, then use a [try/except](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#try) statement when adding a user to an event.  The try will fail if the combination of the event and user are equal.  Post your models.py if you need a more detailed answer.  This is assuming you have a user field in your Registration model.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I've updated my original post.  I'm using the user model from django.contrib.auth.models, and I'm using Django 3.2 - so I guess the unique constraint won't work.